# Can Yuta copy Mahito's Idle Transfiguration?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

In *Jujutsu Kaisen*, Yuta has the ability to copy cursed techniques. Can he copy Mahito's Idle Transfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

Yuta believed his cursed technique to be the **cursed spirit reincarnation** of his **childhood friend** for a very long time. It was only when he truly began to understand Rika that he started unlocking her true potential. After just a few months as a Jujutsu sorcerer, Yuta found that Rika was a near-endless bundle of cursed energy that could reshape itself into imitating any cursed technique.

And so Yuta’s technique became one of the most fearsome abilities in Jujutsu Kaisen. He can **copy the cursed techniques** of other sorcerers, even though they are generally genetic abilities.

The exact requirements for his copy to work are still unknown, but Yuta could copy **Idle transfiguration** and become something worse than Mahito. Yuta should be able to see the soul, as he has captured and manipulated one. Besides, he can one-shot Mahito too, and his **insane cursed energy** will give him enough defense against his enemies.

[image]